# How to stop slide show hide text and image jumping on top while next slide come in?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This Slide show is running perfect with image and text at same time, but the problem arise when you scroll at bottom and every time your next slide changes or come then its jumps on top, don't no why.

This is the reference link : http://new.kingspointcap.com/home

and below is the js code:

```
    /*----------Slideshow of text------------*/

var faderIndex = 2, //to keep track, also it will start from 1st because last value is 0
    faders = $('.fadeTxt'); //cache, so we won't have to walk the dom every time

function nextFade() {

    //fade out element over 3000 milliseconds, after which call a function
    $(faders[faderIndex]).fadeOut(6000, function () {

        //increase the index and do a check, so we won't overflow
        faderIndex++;
        if (faderIndex >= faders.length)
            faderIndex = 0;

        //fade in the next element, after which call yourself infinitely
        $(faders[faderIndex]).fadeIn(3000, nextFade);
    });
}
//get the ball rolling

nextFade();

/*----------Slideshow of text------------*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that the `fadeOut` animation ends with a `display: none;`. Between this `fadeOut` and the next `fadeIn` the document is smaller and the browser has to scroll.

Set the `width` and `height` of the wrapper (the `div` with the `id` *banner*), e.g.:

```
#banner {
    ...
    width: 100%;
    height: 174px;
}
```

Now it should work.